# Twitter Bootstrap popover bug in IE9

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9, popover

I am using the container attribute to place a popover correctly over an SVG element.

```
$(this).popover({
    title: "title",
    placement : "top",
    html : true,
    trigger: "hover",
    content:html,
    container:".visualization"
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/4866/

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE9 (where I can't see the popover whatsoever). Is there a fix?

Comment: It might be helpful to create an example on jsfiddle (fork the [Bootstrap Skeleton](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/)).

Comment: A good question indeed. Seems very weird. Can see the popover in IE, but no matter how I cant manage to show it on top of the SVG, seems like IE moves anything to outside the SVG-area.

Comment: I have the same problem, although slightly different result but that is because of my setup. Can't find an issue on this.